# Regex: Separated by nested parentheses and semicolon

Tags: regex, text, extract, regex-lookarounds

My strings look like the following (each row is one exemplrary string):

```
Smith, Anna (Univ Cambridge); Doe, Jane (Univ Vienna (Austria)); Doe, John (Univ Tokyo; MIT)

Mueller, Hans (FU Berlin (Germany)); Schmid, Julia (); Doe, John (CalTech); Boe, Jane (TU Wien)

Kim, Lee (Nazarbayev Univ (Kazakhstan); Univ Oxford)
```

In other words, the pattern comprises `Surname, Name (Affiliation);` (or without the `;` if no other person follows), whereby the parentheses may be optionally nested `( () )` or contain a `;` or be empty `()`.

I want to extract each name and affiliation, as in:

```
Smith, Anna (Univ Cambridge)
Doe, Jane (Univ Vienna (Austria))
Doe, John (Univ Tokyo; MIT)
Mueller, Hans (FU Berlin (Germany))
Schmid, Julia ()
Doe, John (CalTech)
Boe, Jane (TU Wien)
Kim, Lee (Nazarbayev Univ (Kazakhstan); Univ Oxford)
```

What would be the correct RegEx to do this?

My attempt with `(?<=\()(?:[^()]+|\([^)]+\))+` did not work well...

Comment: If there can only be one nested parentheses level, you can use something like `\w+,\s*\w+\s*\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\);?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/jPbYkE/1))

Comment: Wonderful, thank you, @WiktorStribiżew! Do you want to post it as a full-fledged response so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your expected matches can only have one nested parentheses level, you can use

```js
\w+,\s*\w+\s*\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\);?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jPbYkE/1).

Depending on whether or not your regex library supports recursion, or balanced constructs, this can be further enhanced to match parenthetical phrases of any depth.

*Details*:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\w+\s*` - one or more word and then zero or more whitespace chars
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*` - zero or more sequences of `(...)` substrings with no `(` and `)` in between and then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\);?` - a `)` and then an optional `;`.