# Using regex in tidyR separate_rows() and its "sep"-attribute does not work

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyr

I have these data:

```
df <- data.frame("author" = c("Kardos, NN (Fraunhofer Austria); Laflamme, NN (Fraunhofer Austria); Gallina, NN (Fraunhofer Austria); Sihn, NN (Fraunhofer Austria; TU Wien)", 
        "Demeter, NN (TU Wien; TU Wien); Derx, NN (TU Wien); Komma, NN (TU Wien); Parajka, NN (TU Wien); Schijven, NN (National Institute for Public Health and the Environment; Utrecht University); Sommer, NN (Medical University of Vienna)",
        "Prendl, NN (TU Wien); Schenzel, NN (TU Wien); Hofmann, NN (TU Wien)", 
        "Müller, NN (TU Wien); Knoll, NN (TU Wien; TU Wien); Gravogl, NN (TU Wien; University of Vienna); Jordan, NN (TU Wien); Eitenberger, NN (TU Wien); Friedbacher, NN (TU Wien); Artner, Werner (TU Wien); Welch, NN M. (TU Wien); Werner, NN (TU Wien)"
))
```

With a specific regex (which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331731/regex-separated-by-nested-parentheses-and-semicolon/66331956#66331956)), I am able to extract each person. This works well:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(df$author, "\\w+,\\s*\\w+\\s*\\([^()]*(?:\\([^()]*\\)[^()]*)*\\);?")
```

However, the same regex does not work when I use `tidyr::separate_rows()`:

```
tidyr::separate_rows(df, author, sep = "\\w+,\\s*\\w+\\s*\\([^()]*(?:\\([^()]*\\)[^()]*)*\\);?")
```

How comes? What is the issue here? How can I use that regex with `separate_rows()`?

Comment: Why do you need to split? Extracting is the right way in these cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Because the dataframe actually contains more columns; and I want to keep the other columns intact. With `separate_rows()`, I can "multiply" each row by the number of (splitted) persons.

Comment: Then you need to find another way to define the pattern. What about `"(?<=\\));\\s*"`? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZDowX/1)

Comment: Well, that works as well, thank you. But why is that so that one needs two different regexes for `separate_rows()` and for `str_extract`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is that a regex that is used for *extracting* texts matches the text you need to get. The regex used in a splitting function *removes* the matches and split the original string in the location of the matches.

You can use

```r
tidyr::separate_rows(df, author, sep = "(?<=\\));\\s*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZDowX/1)

*Details*

- `(?<=\))`  - a location immediately preceded with `)`
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

These matches are found and `separate_rows` will split the original strings in the place where the matches occur while removing the match texts.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to repeat the rows of `df` by the `lengths` of the extracted values.

```
values <- stringr::str_extract_all(df$author, "\\w+,\\s*\\w+\\s*\\([^()]*(?:\\([^()]*\\)[^()]*)*\\);?")

result <- transform(df[rep(seq(nrow(df)), lengths(values)), ], author = unlist(values))
```